# How many values of $n$ are there for which $n!$ ends in $1998$ zeros?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, summation, factorial, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> How many values of $n$ are there for which $n!$ ends in $1998$ zeros?

My Attempt:
Number of zeros at end of $n!$ is
$$\left\lfloor \frac{n}{5}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{n}{5^2}\right\rfloor+\dots$$

But is there a method to get converse

Comment: You just need to talk to people to get a converse.

Comment: $$ n/5<1998$$ and $$1998\le n/5+n/5^2$$

Comment: On a serious note, let $f(n)$ be the number of zeros at the end of $n!$.  Then, it can be shown that $$\frac{n+1}{4}-r(n)-\frac{5}{2}<f(n)<\frac{n}{4}\,,$$ where $r(n)$ is the largest integer $k$ such that $5^k\leq n$.  For $f(n)=1998$, $n\leq 5\,f(n)=5\cdot 1998<5\cdot 5^5$, so $r(n)\leq 5$.  This means
$$7992=4\,f(n)<n<4\,f(n)+4\,r(n)+9\leq 8021.$$  The rest is brute-forcing, I guess.  There are only $28$ values to check: $7993$, $7994$, $\ldots$, $8020$.  And you can also assume that $5\mid n$, so this reduces the search greatly to just $5$ numbers: $8000$, $8005$, $\ldots$, $8020$.

Comment: Ahhh, since $n=8000$ works, all answers are $8000$, $8001$, $8002$, $8003$, and $8004$.

Comment: Once you evaluate let's say $n=7995$ (assume answer is not 8000) you can calculate the sum for $n=8000$ by considering which of $\lfloor \frac{n}{5^t} \rfloor$ increases @Batominovski simply by considering divisibility - it increases if and only if $5^t | n$, which is easier than recalculating the whole sum I suppose.

Comment: Note that, without any detailed calculations, we can say that the answer to *how many* values (not *which* values) end in $1998$ (or any other number) of zeros is either five or zero: The number of trailing zeros increases at multiples of $5$ and stays constant in between, so either you hit the exact number you're looking for or you skip over it.

Comment: Yes, so you still need to determine whether it's five or zero, and that requires calculation... @BarryCipra

Comment: @GarethMa, quite right. The sequence https://oeis.org/A000966 is worth a look.

Comment: Or use @Batominovski's answer to obtain a *quite tight* bound, then calculate one value and use my method mentioned above. Should be reasonably quick even by hand.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly notice that if we know $n!$ has 1998 trailing zeros and $n$ is the smallest one with this property, then $n$ must be a multiple of 5, and $n, n+1, n+2, n+3, n+4$ and **only these** satisfy this property. This can be seen from the formula.

Now we must prove that this $n$ exists. (It might not exist - for example, there's no factorial that ends with $5$ trialing zeros) This can be shown by directly checking $n=8000$.

$$Z = 1600 + 320 + 64 + 12 + 2 = 1998$$

And therefore, $n=8000,8001,8002,8003,8004$ satisfies the property required.

Answer (score 2):

As in my comment, let $f(n)$ denote the number of ending zeros of $n!$, for each positive integer $n$.  We define also $r(n)$ to be the largest positive integer $k$ such that $5^k\leq n$.  Then,
$$f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{r(n)}\,\left\lfloor\frac{n}{5^k}\right\rfloor\,.$$
We see that
$$\frac{n+1}{5^k}-1\leq\left\lfloor\frac{n}{5^k}\right\rfloor \leq \frac{n}{5^k}$$
for every $k=1,2,\ldots,r(n)$.  Thus,
$$f(n)\leq \sum_{k=1}^{r(n)}\,\frac{n}{5^k}<\sum_{k=1}^\infty\,\frac{n}{5^k}=\frac{n}{4}\,.$$
This shows that $n>4\,f(n)$, or $n\geq 4\,f(n)+1$.

On the other hand,
$$f(n)\geq \sum_{k=1}^{r(n)}\,\left(\frac{n+1}{5^k}-1\right)=\frac{n+1}{4}\,\left(1-\frac{1}{5^{r(n)}}\right)-r(n)\,.$$
Because $5^{r(n)}\leq n<5^{r(n)+1}$, we see that
$$\frac{1}{5^{r(n)}}<\frac{5}{n}\,.$$
Thus,
$$f(n)>\frac{n+1}{4}\,\left(1-\frac{5}{n}\right)-r(n)=\frac{n-4}{4}-\frac{5}{4n}-r(n)>\frac{n-5}{4}-\frac{5}{16\,f(n)}-r(n)$$
(recalling that $n>4\,f(n)$).  That is, $n<4\,f(n)+4\,r(n)+5+\dfrac{5}{4\,f(n)}$.

If $n\geq 10$ or $f(n)\geq 2$, we obtain $\dfrac{5}{4\,f(n)}<1$; therefore,
$$n\leq 4\,f(n)+4\,r(n)+5\,.$$
Because $n\leq 5\,f(n)$ clearly, we get that $$r(n)=\big\lfloor\log_5(n)\big\rfloor\leq 1+\Big\lfloor\log_5\big(f(n)\big)\Big\rfloor\,.$$
Ergo,
$$4\,f(n)+1\leq n \leq 4\,f(n)+4\,\Big\lfloor\log_5\big(f(n)\big)\Big\rfloor +9\,.$$

Note that, for a given positive integer $m$, there are at most $5$ positive integer $n$ such that $$f(n)=m\,,$$ and such integers $n$ are of the form $5t$, $5t+1$, $5t+2$, $5t+3$, and $5t+4$ for some positive integer $t$.  Therefore, if we are given the value of $m\geq 2$, then we can simply search for $t$ from
$$\left\lceil\frac{4m+1}{5}\right\rceil \leq t \leq \left\lfloor\frac{4m+4\,\big\lfloor\log_5(m)\big\rfloor+9}{5}\right\rfloor\,.$$
(The inequality above is good for $m=1$ as well.)

When $m=1998$, we have $5^4\leq m<5^5$, so that $4\leq \log_5(m)<5$.  Ergo,
$$1599\leq t \leq 1603\,.$$
Therefore, we just need to check which $t\in\{1599,1600,1601,1602,1603\}$ works (there will be at most one possible value).  It turns out that $t=1600$ leads to a solution.  Therefore, all values of $n$ are
$$8000\,,\,\,8001\,,\,\,8002\,,\,\,8003\,,\text{ and }8004\,.$$

It is definitely interesting to find a relationship between $m$ and $t$.  I expect that, for the values $m$ such that there exists a positive integer $t$ such that $m=f(5t)$, we have
$$t=\frac{4m}{5}+\lambda\,\log_5(m)+o\big(\log_5(m))$$
for some positive constant $\lambda\leq \dfrac45$.  What is the value of $\lambda$?  (Gareth Ma kindly helped with the numerical simulation.  It seems we can only say $t=\dfrac{4m}{5}+\mathcal{O}\big(\log_5(m)\big)$.)

Comment: I can do some numerical calculation for this.

Comment: Please do so.  I don't have numerical software on my computer, or am competent enough to do this.  Please let me know when you post the result.

Comment: So you're claiming that, for example, $t=8000$ and $m=1998$ can be related by that $t=\frac{4m}{5} + \lambda \log_5(m)$, correct?

Comment: Yes (approximately), and $m=f(n)$ must have a solution.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a fixed value - https://repl.it/repls/FewGrowlingInstitution (I am calculating $\lambda$ from listing $t$ and calculating $m=f(5t)$.)

Comment: @GarethMa  Thanks!  Maybe the best I could say is that $$\lambda_1:=\liminf_{m\to\infty}\,\frac{t-\frac{4m}{5}}{\log_5 m}\text{ and }\lambda_2:=\limsup_{m\to\infty}\,\frac{t-\frac{4m}{5}}{\log_5 m}$$ are positive real numbers (judging from your numerical results, $\lambda_1\approx0.166$ and $\lambda_2\approx0.277$).

Comment: When I increase $t$ to order of $10^{10}$ those constant seems to decrease. I think it either converges slowly, or it is just $0$ and doesn't exist in the long term. EDIT: $t=10^{15}$ just straight up give $\lambda_1=0$ lmao. I think your error terms are incorrect.

Comment: @GarethMa  I think the precision is just not enough to handle things like this....

Comment: I'll make it use arbitrary precision then.

Comment: Actually you're correct, it's precision problem. I have made it keep 1000 significant figures, and it's "working".

Comment: Now it looks like $\lambda_1\approx 0.1$ and $\lambda_2\approx 0.2$ (I can't say more precisely than this).